# initialize sqlite DB for airflow with ansible

Tags: sqlite, ansible, airflow

I want to create an ansible task to initialize the sqlite database for airflow server.

My ansible task is failing to initialize airflow database when using the following command "airflow initdb". I can successfully initialize the sqlite DB in following two ways:

1. run the command from Python virtual environment when the virtual environment is activated.

```
user@server:~$ source ~/airflow/.venv/bin/activate
(.venv) user@serverr:~$ airflow initdb
```

2. run the command from the shell without activating the virtual environment.

```
user@server:~$ ~/airflow/.venv/bin/airflow initdb
```

I am trying to initialize the database without activating the virtual environment.

Here is my environment:

Server OS: Ubuntu 18.04

Python 3.6.8, Python Virtual Environment: venv (package: python3-venv)

Ansible: 2.8.2, DB: Sqlite, Airflow 1.10.3

My Ansible script:

```
- name: initialize | airflow | database
  shell: "~/airflow/.venv/bin/airflow initdb"
  args:
    executable: "/bin/bash"
  become: yes
```

I also tried with following variations:

```
shell: "airflow initdb"
args:
  chdir: /home/user/airflow/.venv/bin
  executable: "/bin/bash"
become: yes

- name: initialize | airflow | database
  shell: "/home/user/airflow/.venv/bin/airflow initdb"
  become: yes
```

Here is the error message from my ansible script:

```
TASK [airflow : initialize airflow database] ******************************************************************************
fatal: [air]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": "airflow initdb", "delta": "0:00:00.002485", "end": "2019-07-29 11:40:52.737741", "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 127, "start": "2019-07-29 11:40:52.735256", "stderr": "/bin/bash: airflow: command not found", "stderr_lines": ["/bin/bash: airflow: command not found"], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}
```

Any help would be highly appreciated -TIA

Comment: I tried the same setup and I could able to execute the airflow command. quick question what is the host you are targetting? the same ansible-controller machine or a different one?

Comment: @AdaPongaya I am using a remote host to setup the airflow server and running the ansible from my local machine. All my other tasks work fine except the db initialization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the below command should work for you.

```
- name: initialize | airflow | database
  shell: "#!/bin/bash /home/user/airflow/.venv/bin/airflow initdb"
  become: yes
```

Since you are in the sh mode it may not recognize the command you are executing. I am sure some geek will provide a better solution. but for now, you can try this approach.

Following command includes the virtual environment activation and worked for OP:

```
- name: initialize | airflow | database
  shell: "/bin/bash -c 'source /home/transit/airflow/.venv/bin/activate; 
         /home/transit/airflow/.venv/bin/airflow initdb'"
  become: yes
```

Comment: I tried your solution, but did not work. The task creates an empty airflow.db file in the airflow home (in my case ~/airflow ) directory and the airflow client/gui cannot connect to the server from  a browser though the task completes successfully. I had to activate the virtual environment. Following shell command worked for me < shell: "/bin/bash -c 'source /home/transit/airflow/.venv/bin/activate; /home/transit/airflow/.venv/bin/airflow initdb; touch /home/transit/airflow/.initdb.exists'" >. I would like to know how it worked for you or what is the difference between our environment.

Comment: if you could add the additional command to your answer I can accept the answer.